# Unix to datetime object using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to convert a unix time stamp to a datetime object using javascript but am getting a strange output.

The unix timestamps I'm using are `1420243200000` and `1420272000000`.  My javascript code looks like this:

```
function timeConverter(UNIX_timestamp){
  // var a = new Date(UNIX_timestamp*1000);
  // var year = a.getFullYear();
  // var month = a.getMonth()+1;
  // var date = a.getDate();
  // var hour = a.getHours();
  // var min = "0" + a.getMinutes();
  // var sec = "0" + a.getSeconds();
  // var time = date + ' ' + month + ' ' + year + ' ' + hour + ':' + min.substr(-2) + ':' + sec.substr(-2) ;
  // return time;
  var myDate = new Date( UNIX_timestamp *1000);
  time = myDate.toLocaleString();
  return time;
}
```

Neither the commented or uncommented attempts produce the correct date.  I keep getting `9/18/46975, 6:00:00 PM` and `8/17/46976, 2:00:00 AM`as the answers and I can't figure out what's going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your timestamp appears to already be in milliseconds. Don't multiply with 1000.

Calling it "UNIX_timestamp" is misleading. [Unix timestamp is *seconds elapsed since epoch*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time). Timestamps from JS functions (like `Date.now()` and `+new Date()`) are *milliseconds elapsed since epoch*.

Comment: When I don't multiply by 1000 then I get `Invalid Date` as the result.

Comment: @kdubs That's because your variable *is potentially a string*. Try checking.

Comment: Ahhh.  It was a string.  Fixed it by using `var timestamp = parseInt(UNIX_string,10);`  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try `myDate = new Date(1420243200000);`

From the documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Call the constructor `new Date(value);`. Where `value` is "Integer value representing the number of milliseconds since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC (Unix Epoch)."